# Service command on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

I used to be able to execute on the Mac OS X (10.10.5) command line:

```
$ sudo service tomcat7 status
```

However, I must have accidentally deleted the package associated with service command and I am unable to find the name of the service package to reinstall. Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

I can't find service in either /sbin/ or /bin/ or /usr/sbin/

Answer (score 4):

I think you need `launchctl`.

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.tomcat.plist
```

See https://www.joel.lopes-da-silva.com/2008/05/13/installing-tomcat-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: FWIW  `which service` or `mdfind service | grep bin` does not find a `service` command on my system (OS X Yousemite).

Comment: Correct but I was able to do so previously. I had service installed previously but I suppose I accidentally deleted some packages which were hosting service

Comment: @AnilGorthy Maybe you had this installed?  https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew

Comment: No, that is services and not service.

Comment: the issue is with the service command itself, and not tomcat or any other application. I too used to start / stop restart , say (mysql/apache) using service command in my previous mac, however, unable to do so in my new machine.

Comment: apologies! downvote was a mistake, can't upvote again unless you edit the answer.

Comment: @AnilGorthy, yes, it seems there was a package installed in my previous mac as well, however, what I can find is that launchctl is the analog of services in mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start mysql on OSX which is installed through brew, please use this command:

```
brew services start mysql@5.6
```

Update the mysql version based on the system mysql version.